Problems trying to connect Excel to a WebAPI in Azure
I'm trying to call some protected API's from excel but there is no way I can fix
the error:  url: invalid_resource:AADSTS500011: The resource principal ...... was not found in the tenant named .....
I've followed all the steps from here: Source
but for me is not working! Any suggestions ?
!!!!!On my Azure Tenant the URI ID is like : api://CLIENT_ID because my app is not published on Azure. I use Azure just to register it and configure authentication, roles and some other configurations but the app is hosted in my dedicated server so that's why I can't have a URL on the URI ID and this is the cause of the problem but I dont' know how to solve it!!!!!
My API's are in .net core 8 and I'm using Azure AD to authenticate.
Steps to reproduce:

In your backend create a class containing the following code:
public class ExcelAuthenticationFilter : IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{
    public Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        //check if the user is authenticated
        if (!context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            //headers to add
            var headers = new StringValues(new[]
            {
            $"Bearer resource=\"https://management.azure.com/\"",
            $"client_id=\"YOUR_CLIENT_ID\"",
            $"trusted_issuers=\"YOUR_TENANT_ID@YOUR_DOMAIN_ID\"",
            $"token_types=\"app_asserted_user_v1 service_asserted_app_v1\"",
            $"authorization_uri=\"https://login.microsoftonline.com/YOUR_TENANT_ID/oauth2/v2.0/token\""
            });

            // Add headers WWW-Authenticate to th response HTTP
            context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate", headers);

            // Returns 401 (Unauthorized) so excel will show the login popup when calling the api
            context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}


In the desired backend API controller add
[ServiceFilter(typeof(ExcelAuthenticationFilter))]
Example:
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ServiceFilter(typeof(ExcelAuthenticationFilter))]
public class ReportController : ApiControllerBase
{
    // GET: ReportController
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetCustom")]
    public IActionResult GetCustom()
    {
        return Ok();
    }

}


Now open Excel => Data => From Web and write the URL and click OK,
in this case I'm trying it locally so my url is
"https://localhost:44346/api/Report/GetCustom"

Chose Organizational Account and click Sign in

If all the steps are configured correctly you will se a login popup
asking your credentials and after signing the error
invalid_resource:AADSTS500011 will appear



I can reproduced your issue following the reference your shared, but none of the codes shared in that answers helped to solve the issue and I'm afraid this is because we doesn't have a custom domain which used for exposing an API. I also find a related blog which using a custom domain too.

normally speaking, the error occurred when we didn't add the ABC( from The resource principal ABC was not found...) in the API permissions. But when we exposed an API now, we always get the api://xxx as the url when we don't have a custom domain. If we can make ABC  = api://xxx or modify the url as a custom domain and then make the API url to be custom domain, then I think the issue would be resolved.

This case also mentioned it -> the URL to the domain of the service (e.g. http://my.domain.com) must match the App Uri Id in the App Registration

@TinyWang Exactly what I'm talking about, but if I modify the url of my application as a custom domain, I'm afraid that my front end (which uses msal.js to authenticate the user) won't work anymore because it's based on the scopes matching the App Id URI thar are unique unlike the domain which will'be the same for all the enviroments

yes, and I think this is just a not recommending approach as there's no Microsoft document for guiding how to let Excel get data from web api securied by Azure AD. I'm afraid the recommending option is using Garph API to operate the data. I spent all my data on this question and I have to admit that I failed to find out a solution.

I also found this case, and I'm afraid the O365 management API is the reason make it work.

I've tried everything I found but I can't undersand why there is no way to let Excel get data from web api secured by Azure AD given that they both belong to Microsoft enviroment so that would be the ideal solution

yeah it's true, it mighjt relate to the cloud service, because many new features might be available for M365 but not the Excel client.
